# One View controller to rule them all?

Tags: objective-c

My instructor will NOT reply to my e-mails and I'm wasting time messing around like a blind man looking for a quarter in the corner of a round room. Can someone answer a question for me? I'm making a tabbed app with custom cells. My question is....is there only ONE, MAIN view controller that handles everything (super view) or do I need separate, MAIN vc's to handle the different tabs information and functionality?
I tried to do this and ran into giant green squares of "you're duplicating everything Howie" compiler warnings. This tells me I'm going about it the wrong way. If I have fifty tabs, will there be one, main vc that's jammed with code to run (obviously with the exception of classes, delegates etc) all the different vc's I created for the different tabs? Thanks...I should have just come here first.

Comment: You got any code to share with us all???

Comment: code please .. . share it....

Comment: If you're creating a tabbed app, then I'd assume you would start with the tabbed application template.  It shows individual controllers for each tab, which should serve as a reasonable recommendation.  (What "custom cells" have to do with tabs isn't clear to me.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that your instructor is trying to get you to think for yourself. That being said...

Take a step back and break your application's functionality into smaller areas of functionality. Get pencil and paper and draw a picture if you must. It's a hierarchy you'll be constructing.

You will have one view controller that oversees everything else, but you should write additional view controllers for each of those areas of functionality you established earlier (which I am assuming will be displayed in a tab of its own).

I know nothing about these "giant green squares" of which you speak, but it implies that you're having difficulties with your subclassing. Go back to your course materials and review that. Spend some more time on SO. Search for questions already asked about subclassing. Invest the time. It'll be worth it. Then apply those lessons to the hierarchy you constructed.

I've always said that computers are fun, but it can be really tough learning the fundamentals at the outset. Take a deep breath and begin again. And best wishes to you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone. Yes, I DID have to create a separate .h and .m file for each controller I was using. Simple. The instructor did have me think for myself....and I built the app and tore it down twice before building it the correct way. I understand there's a certain amount of "on my own" I need to be aware of...but a simple answer....and I got a one hundred on the project by-the-way, would have saved about 8 hours of un-necessary building. I'm not fluent yet but am trying. Thanks gain for your comments everyone!